# Laravel double auth (api + web cookie)

Tags: laravel

I start creating a Laravel project with api + web.

In the root of the project `/` i will use Laravel web (views).

And for administration i will use Laravel rest api. (in routes : `/api/**`)

I found a problem in authentication, i will use Laravel sanctum for the api auth, and also i need to use cookies for auth in web.

The idea is when admin authenticate with sanctum and enter to administration, he will able to be authenticated also in the web app (in root) but with cookies.

But i have no idea how to combine the 2 ways for authentication.

Comment: you need to set 2 guards, please take a look here https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel/

Comment: Thank you, but i mean that the same user can authenticate in both api + web (jwt and cookie)